# Make grid cell editable on single click, in modern toolkit extjs

Tags: gridview, extjs, extjs6-modern

In modern toolkit extjs, how to make a grid cell editable on single click?
I tried using clickToEdit: 1, as in classic version. But this doesn't work in modern. Can anyone suggest me on this.! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 'triggerEvent' property in the 'gridcellediting' plugin config. Something like this:

```
plugins: {
    gridcellediting: {
        triggerEvent: 'tap', // edit on one click/tap
        selectOnEdit: true
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Arthur, I'm setting a editor for grid cells using childtap method, (childtap: this.onBeforeEditProperty). This doesn't seem to work properly after adding triggerEvent:'tap', what can i do for this?

Comment: Hi @PreethiShettigar, I cannot help you without some fiddle sample or code. I also do not understand exactly what you mean by saying "This doesn't seem to work properly".

Comment: I have added a childtap listener for the grid like this,

listeners:{ scope:this, childtap: this.onBeforeEditProperty }

In 'onBeforeEditProperty' method i am setting editor for the clicked cell,

 ,onBeforeEditProperty: function(editor, context, eOpts){
            var col = context.column;   
            var t = tr.get('type');
            var te = App.getTypeEditor(t, context);
            if(te) {
                 col.setEditor(te);
            }
        }
    }
After adding triggerEvent:'tap', editor doesn't get set.

Comment: @PreethiShettigar why did not you use 'editor' property of the Ext.gird.column.Column class? Something like this: {
            text: 'Date Of Birth',
            dataIndex: 'dateOfBirth',
            flex: 1,

            // Turn on Cell Editing
            editable: true,
            editor: 'datefield' // Date field editor
        }

Comment: For my application, i need different editor's for different cells, in same column. So have to set editor in beforeeditproperty. I have different cells with textfield, datefield within same column.

Comment: Then provide some fiddle.sencha.com sample. Some trivial grid and I will try to help you with this issue.